# rails - getting lots of traffic from semalt and buttons-for-websites.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spam

I just completed an app for a client, and within the first week of registering with Google were seeing around 80% of our traffic from Semalt and buttons-for-websites.com.

Im seeing alot of solutions that involve blocking spammers on the HTaccess level, but since were hosted on Heroku and using rails im not really sure how to do this.

I guess my question is this: do I have to worry about these spammers? And if so how would I prevent access to my rails app?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have to worry about Semalt and the like, other than having them mess up your analytics, but that alone can be annoying.

There is a rack middleware gem for Rails that promises to block Semalt. However, it doesn't block other referral spam. Have a look at: https://github.com/mdippery/rack-block-semalt

Comment: Thanks John, I found that gem and modified it to block Semalt and other referrers.  The day after I deployed the fix, I got the same amount of traffic but from other spam referrers.  Looking at the Heroku logs I can see there requesting Wordpress pages, I guess I dont have much to worry about, at least not from these guys. :S